# How to add a legend to each subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 4 subplots with 4 different lines and I want to make a legend in the upper right corner of each subplot that only shows the line associated with that subplot. How do I do that? I tried `subplot1.legend()` but it throws an error.

**Code for subplot1:**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import beta
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

figure = plt.figure("Figure")
subplot1 = figure.add_subplot(2,2,1)
x = np.linspace (0, 1.0, 200) 
y1 = beta.pdf(x, 10, 7)
subplot1.plot(x, y1, "-", label="r'$\alpha=10, \beta=7$'")
subplot1.legend() #throws an error when I include this statement
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer! I had a typo in my label. I changed the label to:

```
subplot1.plot(x, y1, "-", label=(r'$\alpha=21, \beta=11$'))
```

Comment: BTW: you don't need `()` around `r''`